$n^3+a$ is a power of $2$ for two $n$
Is there an odd positive integer $a$ such that $n^3+a$ is a power of two for at least two positive integers $n\geq 2$?
My hope is in $a=3$ since $1^3+3=2^2$ and $5^3+3=2^7$ - I hope there is at least one more solution. Furthermore, I was able to show that if $m$ and $n$ are solutions with $m>n$, then $m>n^3$. It would be nice if there is an example with $m\leq n^4$.
Any help appreciated!

Needs context please

Remember - interesting is not good enough.

Compute 'x^3+a=2^y over integers' with the Wolfram|Alpha website (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2Ba%3D2%5Ey+over+integers) or mobile app (wolframalpha:///?i=x%5E3%2Ba%3D2%5Ey+over+integers).

Pillai's conjecture: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Pillai%27s_conjecture)
